# How to keep all the text before the last space in a string - R

Tags: r, stringr

I would like to keep all the text that occurs before the last space in a string.

For Example:

```
x<-c("New England Patriots","Carolina Panthers")
```

I have tried `str_extract(x,"\\w+")` but I get back `New, Carolina`.

I would like `New England, Carolina`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
library(stringr)
str_match(c("New England Patriots","Carolina Panthers"), "(^.+)\\s")[, 2]

[1] "New England" "Carolina"
```

This performs a "greedy match". The regex says "everything from the start of the line to the last space".

I used `str_match` instead of `str_extract` to avoid returning the last space itself by returning only the match in parentheses. You could use `str_extract` and then trim the space using *e.g.* `trimws`.

Comment: I know that the \\s is any white space, but could you explain the (^.+) or point me to an article that explains the options.

Comment: `^` = start of line. `.` = "anything". `+` = "keep matching anything". `()` = store this part of the match as a variable (returned using [, 2]). [More information](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html).